# Bootstrap website not responsive in mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, web, responsive

I have a website which must be responsive for mobile phones. I've created it using my desktop. When I adjust browser window it's working perfectly for mobile phone but when I check it on my real mobile phone: OnePlus 2 it's not responsive to the mobile view.

What could be the wrong?

Comment: Code? Did youve add the mobile meta?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> ...

Answer (score 11):

I think you are missing the below meta tag in your html.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

place the above meta tag in your html head tag and see if it works.

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your page?

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code.
Don't use margin or padding attribute forcefully.
Add bootstrap classes instead of them.